# How to use Entity Framework SQL Debug Feature?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to use `Entity Framework SQL Debug Feature` as below however I run into below error,how to fix it?

Code:-

```
DbContext.Database.Log = s => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s);
```

Error:-

```
An object reference is required for the non-static field ,method or property 'System.Data.Entity.DbContext.Database.get'
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the type `DbContext`, you should use an **instance** of that type. For example where you configure the `DbContext`, try to call the method like this:

```
dbContext.Database.Log = s => Debug.WriteLine(s);
```

Replace the `dbContext` variable with whatever you variable name is.

**EDIT**

You context definition should look something like this:

```
public class MyDbContext: DbContext //IdentityDbContext 
{
     public MyDbContext() : base("name=ConnectionStringNameFrom .config")
     {
          Database.Log = e => Debug.WriteLine(e); 
          //or you can define it like this: Database.Log = Console.WriteLine; 
     }
     //{...} your DbSets properties

     //protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
     //{
     // {...}
     //}
}
```

Now if you use this db context example, when debugging your application you should see in the output window the queries executed by EF.

Comment: Hi Mihail - I tried as `var defaultTestPlansRecords = _entities.tblDefaultTestPlans.Where(x => x.SoftwareImage == dtpData.SoftwareImage.ToList();
            defaultTestPlansRecords.Database.Log = s => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s);` I still get the error